# Bokeh get selected glyphs/annotations from TapTool

Tags: python, bokeh

For my project I need to add and remove glpyhs and annotations in bokeh (line, multiline and arrows).  I want to make it as interactive as possible. So in order to remove a glyph/annotation in want to select it with a mouse click and then e.g. delete it with a button. The minimal example would look like that:

```py
import numpy as np
import random
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import Button, TapTool,Arrow,NormalHead
from bokeh.layouts import layout 

from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler

plot = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=600, x_range=(0, 8), y_range=(0, 11),
                   title="Testplot", tools='save, reset, tap')

Lay = layout(children=[])

#adds the glyphs/annotaions to figure
def Click_action():
    x = np.array((random.randrange(1,10),random.randrange(1,10)))
    y = np.array((random.randrange(1,10),random.randrange(1,10)))

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x = x,
                                        y = y))

    arro = Arrow(end=NormalHead(size=5, fill_color="#C0392B"),
                 x_start=random.randrange(0,10),
                 y_start=random.randrange(0,10),
                 x_end=random.randrange(0,10),
                 y_end=random.randrange(0,10),
                 line_width=3,
                 line_color="#C0392B")

    plot.multi_line(xs=[[1,5],[1,1],[3,3],[5,5]],ys=[[5,5],[5,1],[5,1],[5,1]], color='blue', selection_color='red' )
    plot.add_layout(arro)
    plot.line(x='x',y='y', source = source,selection_color='red')
def Click_delet():
    """ Delete the selected Glyphs/Annotations"""
def make_document(doc):

    btn1 = Button(label="Click", button_type="success")

    btn2 = Button(label="Click_delet", button_type="success")
    btn1.on_click(Click_action)
    btn2.on_click(Click_delet)
    Lay.children.append(plot)
    Lay.children.append(btn1)
    Lay.children.append(btn2)
    doc.add_root(Lay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bkapp = {'/': Application(FunctionHandler(make_document))}
    server = Server(bkapp, port=5004)
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    server.io_loop.start()
```

The problems I currently have are:

1. How can I select the arrow ?
2. How do I get all selected glyphs and annotations? (If possible without a CoustomJS callback since  I do not know java that well)
3. Is it possible to select the multiline as one glyph?

I have already solved the issue how to delete lines and arrows from a plot. But I would need the value stored in `plot.renders` and `plot.center` in order to delete them and link them to different classes in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Annotations are not interactive in Bokeh
2. See a minimal example below
3. No

> But I would need the value stored in plot.renders and plot.center in order to delete them and link them to different classes in my project.

Ideally, your workflow should abstain from dynamically creating and removing Bokeh models, especially low-levels ones such as glyphs. If you need to remove a glyph and add a new one with new properties, consider just changing properties of the old glyph. Or maybe just clear the data of the old glyph to hide it.

```py
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource

line_ds = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[0, 3, 7],
                                y=[1, 8, 2]))
multi_line_ds = ColumnDataSource(dict(xs=[[1, 5], [1, 1], [3, 3], [5, 5]],
                                      ys=[[5, 5], [5, 1], [5, 1], [5, 1]]))

p = figure(x_range=(0, 8), y_range=(0, 11), tools='save, reset, tap')

p.line('x', 'y', source=line_ds, selection_color='red')
p.multi_line('xs', 'ys', source=multi_line_ds, color='blue', selection_color='red')

b = Button(label="Delete selected", button_type="success")


def delete_rows(ds, indices):
    print(indices)
    if indices:
        print(ds.data)
        ds.data = {k: [v for i, v in enumerate(vs) if i not in set(indices)]
                   for k, vs in ds.data.items()}
        print(ds.data)


def delete_selected():
    delete_rows(line_ds, line_ds.selected.line_indices)
    delete_rows(multi_line_ds, multi_line_ds.selected.indices)


b.on_click(delete_selected)

curdoc().add_root(column(p, b))
```